# Version ranging in maven not working for project with special characters in their names like "_"

Tags: maven, jenkins, build, range, version

I have explored about version ranging in maven and currently using in my projects along with Jenkins for building. Now I am facing trouble for the projects whose names contain special characters like "_". Jenkins is unable to recognize the latest build version in the range i specified for these projects.

I have a bundle of projects which have to be built in a hierarchy in Jenkins one after the other as shown.
1. projectA's version - 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT. (Released and turned to 0.0.1)
2. Now I will update this projectA version in projectB and triggers a build.

To avoid this multiple times of update in projectB for every release iteration, I have made the version definition in projectB as below.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>myProjects</groupId>
    <artifactId>projectA</artifactId>
    <version>[0.0.1,0.0.99]</version>
 </dependency>
```

Now, I will trigger projectA and I won't update anything in projectB. Now, if I trigger projectB it takes the latest version in the range specified.

Problem :

The issue occurs when I rename the projectA to projectA_1, jenkins is unable to find the latest version in the version range and build failed saying "unable to find the artifact projectA_1:jar:[0.0.1-0.0.99] in cleanroom.dev."

PS: I can't change the project name.

The new dependencies I added are

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>myProjects</groupId>
    <artifactId>projectA_1</artifactId>
    <version>[0.0.1,0.0.99]</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>myProjects</groupId>
    <artifactId>projectA_2</artifactId>
<version>[0.0.1,0.0.99]</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: 1. Check whether the version with `_` is indeed in the repository. 2. the versions maven plugin allows you to update versions to the latest release, and you can also fix the major and minor number of the version. This may be better than using version ranges.

Comment: @JFMeier Thanks for the response

1. Yes, the jar file is present in repo.

The build error shows, there is an illegal charctor in the path and version number is read as null.
[ERROR] myProjects:projectA_1:jar:null

Comment: Usually, artifactId is written in all lowercase with - in between. You are probably better off if you stick to that convention.